# Centre a reveal modal in foundation

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I want to centre position the reveal modal in foundation.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

The I code I used is the following:

```
#quickViewModal{
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  top: calc( 50% - 200px ) !important;
  left: calc( 50% - 300px ) !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

However, this code does not support responsive design. i.e. if the user resizes the window with width 500px lets say, then the modal will be cut off. I also cannot use percentage width.

How can I create a reveal modal that shows and stays at the centre?

UPDATE: it seems that the modal does automatically centre horizontally, but just not vertically.

[image: Foundation Modal not in centre]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following scss.

```
.reveal {
  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    top: 50% !important;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

You need to use `!important` on the `top` attribute to overwrite the javascript value that foundation sets.

You need to also allow for the breakpoints. On mobile, you want the reveal to be full screen.

It looks like you are not using scss so you would need to have something like.

```
@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  #quickViewModal{
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    top: 50% !important;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise that this was from nearly 3 years ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

foundation reveal modal by default is responsive and centered...
to limit its size to 600px add the following CSS (after the foundation's CSS):

```css
.reveal-modal {
   max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: It does not automatically centre vertically though. (see image)